# MongoDB percentage query with multiple $project stages in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB. I am looking for expert views about the query I wrote. basically I am calculating the percentage of skills that were in demand in the past 90days. The Query I have written gives the desired output but I feel like this query can be optimized. Kindly point out my mistakes so I can optimize this query with a better understanding of MongoDB.

Sample Document:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"630a2ba9fe850ebc2d2f4a25"
   },
   "category":{
      "name":"SQL",
      "path":",web development,",
      "id":{
         "$oid":"62fe35f3f1793d2014bfe05f"
      }
   },
   "createdAt":{
      "$date":{
         "$numberLong":"1661610921812"
      }
   }
}
```

My Query:

```
const SkillsInDemand = await Job.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { createdAt: { $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) }}
      },
      {
        $group: { _id: "$category.name",count: { $sum: 1 }}
      }, 
      {
        $project: {count: "$count",total: {$sum:count} }
      },
      {
        $project: { percentage: { $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$count", "$total" ] }, 100] }}
      },
      { 
        $sort: { percentage: -1 } 
      }
    ])
```

$group stage output:

```
[
  { _id: 'Flutter', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'SQL', count: 2 },
  { _id: 'Python', count: 9 }
]
```

1st $project stage output:

```
[
  { _id: 'Python', count: 9, total: 12 },
  { _id: 'Flutter', count: 1, total: 12 },
  { _id: 'SQL', count: 2, total: 12 }
]
```

2nd $project stage output:

```
[
  { _id: 'Python', percentage: 75 },
  { _id: 'Flutter', percentage: 8.333333333333332 },
  { _id: 'SQL', percentage: 16.666666666666664 }
]
```

Final Output:

```
[
  { _id: 'Python', percentage: 75 },
  { _id: 'SQL', percentage: 16.666666666666664 },
  { _id: 'Flutter', percentage: 8.333333333333332 }
]
```

Comment: `$project: {count: "$count",total: {$sum:count} }` - can you tell what are values of `count` and `total` after this stage? Also, include a sample document of your input collection in your post.

Comment: count: "$count": is the no. of jobs that demanded a specific skill.
total: {$sum:count}: is the no. of total jobs.
I am using (count/total)*100 to get the percentage of skill demanded in total jobs.
10 Jobs, 1 Python job, (1/10)*100 = Python job demand is 10%

Comment: SkillsInDemand [
  { _id: 'Flutter', count: 1, total: 12 },
  { _id: 'SQL', count: 2, total: 12 },
  { _id: 'Python', count: 9, total: 12 }
]

Comment: At the first `$project` stage I get an error.

Comment: share the error